# Wave equation IVP on arbitrarily shaped 2D domain

Tags: waves, hilbert-space

I’m interested in simulating a wavetable of arbitrary shape.

> Formally, suppose $R ⊂ \mathbb{R}^2$ is a region whose boundary is a simple closed curve $γ$. Let $u = 0$ on $γ$, and let $u$ satisfy the wave equation in $R$. For an initial value problem, let $u = f(x, y)$ initially.

***Idea:***

Perhaps one could find a complete basis of standing wave functions $u_i(x, y)\cos(ω_it)$, so that a solution could be written as a series $u = Σ_i α_i u_i \cos(ω_it)$ by finding the coefficients $α_i$?

To motivate this,
consider the simple example $R = [0, π]×[0, π]$. The 2D Fourier basis $u_{nm} = \sin(nx)\sin(my) \ ∀_{(n,m)∈\mathbb{N}^2}$ is orthonormal<sup>†</sup> in $\mathcal{C}(R)$, and any $u_{nm}$ is a standing wave solution with frequency $ω_{nm} = c^2(n^2 + m^2)$, so that $u_{nm}\cos(ω_{nm}t)$ solves the wave equation. Finally, we can decompose $f$ in this basis with $α_{nm} = ⟨f, u_{nm}⟩$ so that $u = Σ_{nm}α_{nm}u_{nm}\cos(ω_{nm}t)$ is the solution to our IVP.

Does this approach generalise? For general regions, I’m not sure whether standing wave solutions exist, or whether they always form a basis. Do they? If so, how might one find them?

---

†<sub>With respect to an inner product like $⟨f, g⟩ ≡ \frac{4}{π^2}∫_0^π∫_0^π fg\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$.</sub>

Comment: In a general sense, as long as you have periodic boundary conditions and your solution is well behaved in-between, yes you can expand in plane waves.

Comment: May I ask why this has the "hilbert-space" tag?

Comment: @probably_someone Because I describe the standing waves as elements in an inner product space. I suppose it’s not relevant enough.

Comment: @InertialObserver What if the boundary conditions cannot be interpreted as periodic? (If the region does not tesselate, for example.)

Comment: @Jollywatt On the contrary, that's definitely relevant.

Comment: Then you use a Fourier transform. You don’t need periodicity for that.

Comment: If I understand your approach it does generalize in theory.  But you need to be able to apply the boundary conditions and get a meaningful solution.  Are you planning in doing that numerically, over a finite descretization?

Comment: I tried something like this years ago on a piecewise linear domain boundary.  It worked by was messy.

Comment: @ggcg Yes, I would be using a numerical method. Honestly, I’m just playing with wave animations in python. Did your method involve iteratively finding standing waves?

Comment: @InertialObserver Would you be able to outline the Fourier transform method?

Comment: I set up the condition for stationary waves to meet all boundary conditions.  I don't recall it having an iterative component but it had a lot of B.C. elements which required solving a large matrix equation.  Your post implies that you want to keep the {sin, cos} bases unless I misunderstood.  You could solve the f-domain wave equation using FEM, FD method, Relaxation, and you'll need the eigen frequency to be a variable since you don't know it.  But the equation for it is easy d(w_nm) = 0 w/r to every variable.

Comment: Maybe you should read about it first